# Is there any way to Merge these two java-stream operations?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of invoices that each can have an `ISSUED` status or `IsNotfied` field that could be `false` or both conditions. I want to know, is there any way that I can do the operations simultaneously and do the operation in only one stream?

```
allInvoices.stream()
    .filter(invoice -> invoice.getCurrentStatus().getStatus().equals(EInvoiceStatus.ISSUED))
    .forEach(this::submitInvoiceForPayment);

allInvoices.stream()
    .filter(invoice -> !invoice.getIsNotified())
    .forEach(invoice -> sendInvoiceNotification(invoice.getInvoiceDocument(), invoice));
```

Comment: Well, to me it seems that your operations are different. Like, you execute different code on both cases. So its not done with a simple `filter (x -> first || second)`. You would also need to remember the state which matched for your action. At which point, using streams isnt really helpful anymore. It would decay to a simple `allInvoices.forEach(invoice -> { if (...) first(); else if (...) second(); }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functional programming features doesn't buy you anything in this case because your code needs to operate via [*side-effects*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects) (*which might lead to unexpected behavior if someone would modify these streams by making them parallel*), and also because these *side-effects* should be triggered by different conditions.

I would suggest sticking with a plain `for`-loop:

```
for (Invoice invoice : allInvoices) {
    if (!invoice.getIsNotified())
        sendInvoiceNotification(invoice.getInvoiceDocument(), invoice);
    if (isIssued(invoice))
        submitInvoiceForPayment(invoice);
}
```

```
public static boolean isIssued(Invoice invoice) {
    return invoice.getCurrentStatus().getStatus().equals(EInvoiceStatus.ISSUED);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The only obvious way to do it would be:

```
allInvoices.stream()
    .forEach(invoice -> {
      if (invoice.getCurrentStatus().getStatus().equals(EInvoiceStatus.ISSUED)) {
        submitInvoiceForPayment(invoice);
      }
      if (!invoice.getIsNotified()) {
        sendInvoiceNotification(invoice.getInvoiceDocument(), invoice);
      }
    });
```

which is basically just a for loop.

I'd stick with it as it is, or use a for loop.